# NA values displayed as label in map

Tags: r, label, shapefile

I have a shapefile `shp`. I want to plot this file for a particular attribute `sl5` using `spplot`. This attribute has NA values for a number of polygons. So when I plot this using following code:

```
    sp.label <- function(x, label) {
  list("sp.text", coordinates(x), label,cex=0.8)
}
ISO.sp.label <- function(x) {
  sp.label(x,as.vector(round(x$sl5,0)))
}
make.ISO.sp.label <- function(x) {
  do.call("list", ISO.sp.label(x))
}
my.palette <- brewer.pal(n = 5, name = "YlOrRd")
spplot(shp['sl5'], col.regions = my.palette,cuts=4, sp.layout = make.ISO.sp.label(shp))
```

I get the following:
[image]

The problem that I need help with is that I do not want NA values to display as labels on the map.

Comment: Naive way is to replace NA with empty string '', will that work?

Comment: Thanks it actually worked! :)